# How to get rid of this error?

Tags: c++, numbers, decimal

I was assigned to do a simple number converter, I followed all the instructions and they seemed pretty straight forward. This is for a beginner course into C++ and I seem to be missing the mark on this program. I continue to get an error stating that I need an initializer before double inputedNumber or that the variable is not in the scope. I have even compared my code to classmates and did what they did but this error still happens...
Any help would be awesome!
Thanks in advance!

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
       double inputedNumber;
       cout << "Please input a decimal to be converted.";
       cin >> inputedNumber;
       cin >> "Number Converter!! The given number is" >> inputedNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Voting to close as trivial typo etc. You need a trailing `;` after the `inputedNumber` declaration.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after inputedNumber;

Comment: You forgot `;` after `inputedNumber`.

Comment: Even with the trailing ; an error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin >> "Number Converter!! The given number is" >> inputedNumber;
```

does not compile, since `cin` is only for *input* not *output*; use `cout` instead!

```
cout << "Number Converter!! The given number is" << inputedNumber;
```

Also, if you really want to convert a number (to an integer for example) use this:

```
cout << "Number Converter!! The given number is" << static_cast<int>(inputedNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you for constructive help! The missing semicolon helped one problem but the main problem was the issue behind bin and cout. You are very helpful!

Comment: Thanks. Good luck with your further programming!

Answer (score 0):

First Line in main function is missing a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you for partially solving the issue